# Google Calendar Delegates?

Tags: ical, google-calendar, google

I've decided to start using my Google Calendar through iCal on my Mac. Although I've got a question regarding an annoying issue I'm having.

When I go about adding calendars to my Google Calendar and sync it via iCal, it puts the main calendar where it's supposed to, then it puts the rest of my calendars under a heading called 'Delegates'. I don't know what it means, but is there a way to stop Google from doing this? I just want all my calendars to appear under one heading, the Google one (like the incoming payments calendar in the image below)

I'm not sharing any calendars with any friends or family and I still just can't work this out. Please help me find out where I'm going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using Google calendars when iCloud came out, but from what I remember, the delegates thing is just a side effect of how Google implements additional calendars in the CalDAV protocol. I don't think there's anything you can do about it. The upside is that it doesn't break any functionality, it's just a bit annoying in how iCal displays them.